# Steps to find gradient of this?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I don't understand how to get from .54 to .55, any help?
[image: question]

Edit:
Wolfram alpha gives the answer as this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=grad+Ucos%28theta%29%28r%2Ba%5E2%2Fr%29

I can't seem to convert their answer to the answer needed even though it is similar.

Comment: Do try to make your question self-contained.

Comment: @freak_warrior ah I see thanks, didn't know the format.

Comment: It's also best to show your working so far :)

Comment: @Shaun I just have the forumla for cylindrical gradient so far, if i get down anything useful on paper I'll put it up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Remember that $x = r\cos(\theta)$ in cylindrical coordinates. You have 
$$
\phi = U \, r\cos(\theta) + U \, \frac{a^2}{r} \cos(\theta) = U\,x+U\,\frac{a^2}{r}\cos(\theta)
$$
Take this gradient in cylindrical coordinates (with $x$ the rectangular coordinate)
$$
\nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\mathbf{\hat{e}_x} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} \mathbf{\hat{e}_{\theta}} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \mathbf{\hat{e}_{r}} \\
= U\mathbf{\hat{e}_{x}} + U \frac{1}{r}\left( - \frac{a^2}{r} \sin(\theta) \right)\mathbf{\hat{e}_{\theta}} + U \left( - \frac{a^2}{r^2} \cos(\theta) \right) \mathbf{\hat{e}_{r}}$$
Now, after minor algebraic manipulation you will see that the equation you are curious about is exactly $- \nabla \phi$.

Comment: great, thanks tom!